# Retrieve deleted Heartbeat activity

Tags: heartbeat

I am using D7 + [Hearbeat module](https://drupal.org/project/heartbeat)

Previously my heartbeat setting was when cron runs delete activities older than a month. So a cron run removed the activities.

Is there any way of retrieving the deleted heartbeat activities?

Comment: Sorry, once you delete data from database, only http://serverfault.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/ can help you. I'm afraid unless you have backups or can send server's hdd to data recovery company, your cause is lost. Unless that's not what you wanted, and you need to act when data still exists? If so, please rephrase your question.

Comment: This is indeed off-topic here. I can't migrate it to superuser or dba as it won't make sense there in its current format. If you want to post to one of those sites (I'd recommend dba personally) try making your question more about the generic issue of recovering deleted data, and include more details about your current setup and what's actually happened

Comment: actually i just wanted to know whether this is possible or not. I did not find anything over the internet, did not get an answer on irc, but i needed an answer even if its a no so that i could go about searching for a different solution to my problem.
Well...thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so because data was deleted from database. If u have old copy of database, then here you can do something,
Create an other database and import that old database into it.
and Fetch the required tables(means required rows and column) and dump into your current database.

Comment: thanks. needed an answer to this, yes or no. Now i know i gotto try out something completely different to solve my problem. Thanks again.